# Which is faster 'res.end(data)' or 'res.write(data);res.end()', why?

Tags: node.js, http, runtime, node-modules

[Here(click me)](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L486) is the source code .

I think they are the same speed of execution, they all need to be judged the arguments .

Whats your thought on this ?

Comment: Please include the source code in the question. Otherwise the question might get useless to others if the link changes.

Comment: I add the link at **Here** 0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res.end(data)` [ultimately calls `res.write(data)`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js#L528).  The speed difference is going to be minimal compared to server noise, so I would go with the one that semantically makes more sense for your application.

The [documentation confirms this](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding)

> If data is specified, it is equivalent to calling response.write(data, encoding) followed by response.end().